# HashMap to SQL when Key is an enum

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I have the following entity class:

```
public class SportData {
//other attributes

 @Column(name = "POINTS")
    @ElementCollection
    private Map<NBAEvent, Integer> points;
}


public enum NBAEvent {
    THREE_POINT,
    TWO_POINT,
    FREE_THROW,
    //..
}
```

When I generate the corresponding tables using `ddl-auto: validate` it creates the NBAEvent(which is the k) column with the data type as an integer`(points_key int4 NOT NULL)`.

1. How can I generate a varchar type column for the points key column?
2. If I manually write the SQL like `points_key CHARACTER VARYING(255)` how would it affect?

I'm using Spring boot along with Spring JPA, DB is PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the key of your Map is an enum then you must also add the `MapKeyEnumerated` annotation.

The key is to declare it with the `EnumType.STRING` type.

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "colltable")
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name="POINTS")
private Map<NBAEvent, Integer> map;
```

Otherwise as per javadocs it defaults to: `javax.persistence.EnumType.ORDINAL`. And that results in an integer table while ddl creation.

you may also need the `@CollectionTable` annotation as above.